# ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, content-provider

Tengo una aplicacion de reportes en el que tengo algunos filtros, pero al momento de cambiar el valor de los filtros el Widget en el que tengo mis datos no recibe ningun cambio, e estado buscando maneras de hacer que cuando se altere alguno de los datos de los filtros el widget recargue con los nuevos datos pero ninguno funciona :(

```
class ReportesGeneral extends StatefulWidget {
  String estado;
  String pagina;
  String busqueda;
  String perdidas;
  ReportesGeneral(
      {required this.estado,
      required this.pagina,
      required this.busqueda,
      required this.perdidas,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  createState() => _ReportesGeneralState();
}

class _ReportesGeneralState extends State<ReportesGeneral> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map DataFilt = {
      //Lista de filtros que envio a un API
      "estado": widget.estado,
      "pagina": widget.pagina,
      "busqueda": widget.busqueda,
      "perdidas": widget.perdidas
    };
    setState(() {
      DataFilt;
    });
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ReporteProvider(DataFilt),
          lazy: false,
        ),
      ],
      child: ResportWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Esa es un pagina principal? Si notificaste en el Main que manejaras el estado por medio de ChangeNotifier?

Comment: No es la pagina principal, pero creo que el problema es que no notifique con el ChangeNotifier, voy a intentar colocarlo a ver si ahora funciona.

Comment: Gracias ya lo resolvi agregando mi ChangeNotifierProvider en el main y ejecutando los filtros dentro de su create :)